# Is there a program that finds an approximation function when the points and their derivatives are known?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, differential-geometry, computational-mathematics

I was working on an indefinite integral problem and found a case where the solution could not be represented analytically, but I wanted to graph it.
That is, I know the f(0) value of a function, and I know the derivative at several points (through computer calculations). At this point, is there a program that can find the equation of a function that connects the points consecutively?

Comment: There is Hermite interpolation. You could also compute a piecewise polynomial function with cubic polynomials as the pieces. The coefficients of the cubic pieces are determined completely by the values and derivatives for that segment. You would have to check your available interpolation functions if they can take derivatives into account. You could also fill/refine the values table sparsely with cubic interpolation values, 3 to 10 per segment, and then use a better than piecewise linear interpolation of the values to generate the data for the plot.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!